# C# Selenium use GoUrl then cannot findElement it always timeout

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

can i async load this page. I donot need the document all loaded then can be find elements.
 I need loading page can be findElement and execute js right now
 how can i do this?

```
// this Url page contains a so many large JS file.
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url); // waiting for 10s
// after 10s the code will throw timeout exception.
// and cannot Run this code:
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(Js); // this code it throw Timeout Exception
```

---

[gourl is timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W3XD.jpg)

### [but the page is is load , and a js file is pedding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WlHb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qidl.jpg)

---

ExecuteScript error message is :
**timeout
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)**

Comment: But why do you need `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(Js);` in your code? Please explain more about your test scenario.

Comment: thank you for response to me, this my first tip on stackoverflow. i very happy.

Comment: this JS is nothing ,My point is why do anything it will be Timeout? just on after GoURL timeout. Any executeScript and findElement always timeout. can I donot wait page all loaded to findElement?

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: ok ,I update the question ,can you understand my point?